# How should I do to extract correctly, from a React FC, the function that brings the Firebase docs with onSnapshot? I am using ionic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to extract the query from a firebase collection and take it out of the component but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

I am using Firebase, Ionic, React.

This is my component: I could easily do this or replace the get by onsnapshot but the idea is to be able to extract the firebase part of the component to a different file so create the function `getlList ('movies')`.

```
...

import { getList } from '../../firebaseConfig';

const Peliculas: React.FC = () => {
  const [listMovies, setListMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([])
  const [newMovie, setNewMovie] = useState<Movie>()

  const listLoading = async () => {
/*    
    try {
      let list:Movie[] = [];
      const res = await firebase.firestore().collection("movies").get();
      res.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push(createMovie({
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          description: doc.data().description
        }))
      })
      setListMovies(list)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
*/

    getList("movies").then(result => {
      setListMovies(result)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
  }

  useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    listLoading()
  })
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Blank</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonList>
        {listMovies.map((movie) => {
              return (
                <IonItem>
                  <ItemListPelicula movie={movie} delete={() => {}} />
                </IonItem>
              )
            })}
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Peliculas;
```

the other file where the function to obtain the documents would be is this: I understand that I should not use a promise in the case of onsnapshot but I don't know how to do it then, because if or if I want to use onSnapshot.

```
...


export async function getList(collection: string) {
  let list: Movie[] = []
  await firebase.firestore().collection(collection)
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      list.push({
        id: doc.id,
        description: doc.data().description,
        title: doc.data().title,
      })
    });
    return list
  }, error => {
    return error;
  })

  return list
}
```

Comment: Please don't use all-caps as that is perceived as yelling.